# How do I get my function to run when a criteria is met?

Tags: javascript

I've written some code in JS that's basically supposed to work like a CSS media query and start this slideshow when the viewport width threshold has been crossed. I know it works because it runs when I call the function in the console, but I cannot figure out why it won't just run on it's own as intended.

I'm guessing I've either done something wrong with the responsive part or there's a super basic error somewhere that I've yet to learn.

So far I've tried "window.InnerWidth", I've tried "screen.width" "document.body.clientWidth" and "window.matchMedia" (and to be honest, I would love to know more about each because I'm fairly new to JS).

Here's the snippet:

```
function resetCards() {
  card.forEach(elem => elem.classList.remove("show"));
}
function showCards(index) {
  resetCards();
  card[index].classList.add("show");
}
function cardSlide() {
  var i = 1;

  function loop() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      showCards(i);
      i++;
      if (i < card.length) {
        loop();
      } else if (i == card.length) {
        i = 0;
        loop();
      }
    }, 4000);
  }
  loop();
}

function runShow() {
  var i = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1024px)");
  if (i.matches) {
    cardSlide();
  } else {
    console.log("Error!");
  }
}
runShow();
```

Comment: you're calling the function only once on load, look into adding a resize event listener and calling your function then: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize

Comment: @MarkBaijens - I do not. I naively assumed it would run immediately. Will look into Event Handlers. It seems to be what everyone's bringing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code only checks **once**. But the good news is that `matchMedia` returns [an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList) that as a [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/onchange) event you can hook into that gets triggered whenever the result of the media query changes:

```
function runShow(e) {
  if (e.matches) {
    cardSlide();
  }
}
window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1024px)").onchange = runShow;
```

If you want it to run once right away, you need to do that proactively:

```
function runShow(e) {
  if (e.matches) {
    cardSlide();
  }
}
var match = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1024px)");
match.onchange = runShow;
runShow(match);
```

[Live Example](https://output.jsbin.com/moyalipane)

That example doesn't do anything when the query goes from matching to non-matching. You might want to do something in an `else` or similar.

Comment: Such a simple and straightforward solution! I still can't seem to get it to work, though.

Comment: @jollyjwhiskers - My original answer only showed hooking it up, but didn't force the first run, perhaps that's the problem? I've updated and added a live example.

Comment: Turns out that the problem was that my variable needed to be on top! Problem solved and I thank you very much, sir!

Answer (score 0):

The reason it won't check the width after a certain time is because you are using the `setTimeout` function, this will only run once. If you want it to check multiple times you should use the `setInterval` function.

You however want to avoid this as it is not accurate / efficient. you could use eventlisteners instead!

Like one of the answers here stated, you are able to use the `onchange` event of the `window.matchMedia` object.